# Page variable in for loop file name

Tags: jekyll, liquid

For a bilingual website, i have yaml data files for 2 languages.

files example:

```
en_services.yml
fr_services.yml
```

Variable example in my page:

```
---
lang: en
---
```

I want to loop trough the file with the lang as the prefix, something like that:

```
{% for service in site.data.{{ page.lang }}_services %}

{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work, is there a way I can do that?

By the way, I don't think I can add subfolders in the _data folder, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that doesn't work, if you are able to put them both in the same file (grouped under the appropriate language code) there is a solution.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/dhutchison/8548106) was for another example based on post authors, but your should be able to use the same setup using language codes instead of author names.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
site.data[{{ page.lang }} + '_services']
```

data[i] has key/value entries for all the files in your _data directory, and passing the string in, like so (for /_data/book.yaml):

```
site.data['book']
```

...totally works and opens up the possibility of concatenating strings inside the brackets with whatever variable you want. :)

Comment: HUGE +1. This is really the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
{% capture thefile %}{{ page.lang }}_services{% end capture %}
{% for service in site.data[thefile] %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Should do the trick.